# How to implement direct transitions between sibling pages in Xamarin.Forms with ReactiveUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, reactiveui

I need to implement the routing functionality in Xamarin.Forms application using the ReactiveUI framework.

The following transitions map needs to be implemented:
[image: Navigation map]

￼
Above the black arrows show forward transitions (e.g. I go from the Menu to the Order page by clicking on the menu item button), while the red arrows are for Go Back functionality. Please note that Go back should work for both: (a) the "Go back" link in the top navigation bar (b) the hardware «Back» button on the Android devices.

How do I implement the transitions between sibling pages like these:

- Menu - Order - Map - Back to the Menu
- Menu - Order - Order details - Pin details page - Back to the Map - Back to the Menu
  ?

P.S. Here is the guide https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/ I followed recently, so I used GoNext/GoBack commands to implement more simple transitions like Menu - Order - Order details - Back to the Order - Back to the Menu. It does not work well for the described case, as the Back buttons make transitions back to the previous page instead of their parent page in the navigation map.

Answer (score 2):

The `NavigateBack` command implementation is [quite simple in ReactiveUI's RoutingState](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/a6c5dcf4f0ce82a9c0c8b05d7c78f80cd57028d1/src/ReactiveUI/Routing/RoutingState.cs#L136), it just removes the last element from the `RoutingState.NavigationStack`, `RoutingState.NavigationStack` is an instance of `ObservableCollection<IRoutableViewModel>`.

So in your particular case, you could write your own `NavigateBack` command implementation that mutates the navigation stack as required by your application domain. You could use a `switch` block to figure out what page is currently shown in the screen, and then map that page into another page, either newly created or stored in a field or in a `Locator.Current`. Probably your command will require a more complex `canExecute` implementation as well.

```cs
ReactiveCommand<Unit, IRoutableViewModel> navigateBackDomainAware =
    ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => {
        var currentViewModel = NavigationStack[NavigationStack.Count - 1];
        if (currentViewModel is PinDetailsViewModel) {
            var mapViewModel = GetMapViewModel();
            NavigationStack.Add(mapViewModel); // The navigation.
            return Observable.Return(mapViewModel);
        } else {
            // Handle other pages. You can also put some domain-specific code
            // describing the navigation mappings in your application here.
        }
    });
```